# Passing function as an argument to another function

Tags: go

**Original**

How can go call a function without passing parameters

I am fairly new to go. `SignInHandler` expect a parameter of type `*gin.Context`, but this is not explicitly passed during function call `authHandler.SignInHandler`. Is there some sort of implicit passing or special case for context, I am not sure.

---

**Update**

I originally thought that it is **calling** the function, but it is simply **passing** the function reference.

main.go

```
package main

var authHandler *handlers.AuthHandler

func init() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    authHandler = &handlers.AuthHandler{}
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/signin", authHandler.SignInHandler)
}
```

auth.go

```
type AuthHandler struct{}

func (handler *AuthHandler) SignInHandler(c *gin.Context) {

}
```

Comment: `but this is not explicitly passed during function call authHandler.SignInHandler` Well, thats not a function call to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing special in `Context` argument treatment. It's argument as any other.

`router.POST("/signin", authHandler.SignInHandler)` is not `authHandler.SignInHandler` function call (note there are no `()` at the end). Instead it is passing the function as an argument of [`HandlerFunc` type](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/55e27f12465e058058180280d5f0bdc473eb3302/gin.go#L47) to `router.POST()` for later invocation (when handling route).

When server is handling request for that route; handler function will be run (by `gin`) and under the hood it will indeed be called with the `Context` argument as usual. That `Context` will be provided by caller (usually middleware or http server).

See small [demonstration in playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RALCidT6oCV) that shows this concept without the complexity of gin codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't need a parameter in your example, because that code doesn't explicitly call the function. Function calls happen with the calling syntax, beginning with `(`, ending with `)`, with arguments (if any) in between.

Functions are first class values in Go, so you can reference them without calling them. For example:

```golang
func myFunc() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("- Beginning")

    // Assign the function to a variable.
    var someFuncVar = myFunc

    fmt.Println("- Middle")

    // Now call the function variable.
    someFuncVar()

    fmt.Println("- End")
}
```

Outputs:

```
- Beginning
- Middle
Hello
- End
```

[Try it yourself](https://go.dev/play/p/Rqt7h6MBQpe)

`authHandler.SignInHandler` is technically called a "method value" (defined [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values)), which is a slightly more advanced version of this. By referencing the method name (`SignInHandler`) through an instance (`authHandler`), you get a function value which is bound to that particular instance.

Here's a more formal definition from the language spec:

> If the expression x has static type T and M is in the method set of type T, x.M is called a method value. The method value x.M is a function value that is callable with the same arguments as a method call of x.M. The expression x is evaluated and saved during the evaluation of the method value; the saved copy is then used as the receiver in any calls, which may be executed later.